# Problem with "touch sensitivity" on iPhone calendar

Tags: iphone

After installing the latest software update, my calendar on my iPhone 5s has lost it's "sensitivity". I cannot just touch a date to see my scheduled events. I must the date over and over, with much for "force" than before. There is also a similar type of problem with my iPad since the last update. It take MUCH more force to close an app with the "finger pinch".